# FXML file in Netbeans keeps reverting changes to original copy?

Tags: java, xml, maven, javafx, fxml

I'm working on a JavaFX application, and my FXML file keeps reverting back to its original changes whenever I build the file with dependencies in NetBeans.

Building with dependencies is the only way I can "save" changes with Maven, and whenever the build is complete, Notepad++ will inform me that the files have been changed and ask if I want to reload them (to which I click "NO"). If I have the FXML files open IN notepad++, then the changes are saved for that particular build, and if I run the project, everything works fine. The problem lies if I close my FXML files, and attempt to build the dependencies. Then, my changes are overwritten with the original code I had (I pulled the project from GitHub), and to get my changes back, I have to go to a commit I made. Is there some setting I missed when importing the Maven project into NetBeans? I am completely new to Maven and JavaFX (not programming or Java), so if I missed something trivial, please forgive me. Thanks!

Comment: When open in NetBeans, what is the path (relative to the project directory) of the FXML file you're editing?

Comment: @Slaw It's just a couple of folders deep within the project...

Comment: I'm just making sure you're editing the FXML file from under `src/main/resources` and not `target/classes` (probably not the likely cause of your issue, but just in case).

Comment: @Slaw Oh... yeah... it's under that... I didn't think it was relevant. Should I swap my FXML files away from the target/classes directory?

Comment: All files under `target` are the output. The files under `target/classes` specifically are the compiled source files (i.e. `*.class`) and _copied_ resource files. The source files are under `src/main/java` and the resource files you should edit are under `src/main/resources`. Your issue is probably the following: You'd edit the file under `target/classes`, run Maven, and Maven would copy the file from `src/main/resources` and overwrite your changes.

Comment: @Slaw Aha... see, this is what happens when you're asked to pick up on a project where other undergrads left off xD. What I mean by that is, NONE of the FXML files were in the src/main/resources folder; they were only in the output (target/classes) directory. That fixed it. Thank you!